# simplest bash string comparison in makefile is failing

Tags: string, bash, makefile, conditional-statements

My makefile is as follows:

```
test:
    if [ "a" == "a" ]; then echo "hooray"; fi
```

running `make test` yields the following error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: [: a: unexpected operator
```

(Note, if I change the conditional to `"a" == "b"`, the error still refers to `"a"`, so the "problem" is (at least) with the first "a").

I feel like I must be missing something silly, but I cannot get this to work, and can't think of any way to further simplify the problem.

I'm on a raspberry pi (raspbian), running the default/latest everything (`apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` daily).

Answer (score 2):

Gah. The clue is `/bin/sh`. apparently make doesn't use `bash` as its shell under my configuration? very strange...

Anyways, `==` *isn't* POSIX sh. Even this cheat sheet: https://www.joedog.org/articles-cheat-sheet/ gets it wrong (thank you Rebecca Cran, who commented as such a year ago...)

To be clear- the solution is to use a single `=`, as in:

```
test:
    if [ "a" = "a" ]; then echo "hooray"; fi
```

Comment: The relevant specification lives at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html

Comment: (and that's not just "under [your] configuration"; `make` *always* uses `/bin/sh` unless explicitly told to do otherwise).

Comment: Make always uses `/bin/sh` by default.  You can change it by setting the `SHELL` variable in your makefile.  However, on some systems (particularly Red Hat-derived systems) `/bin/sh` is a symlink to bash.  On other systems (particularly Debian-derived systems), `/bin/sh` is a symlink to `dash` which is intended to be a more-or-less strict POSIX emulation shell.  So it depends more on your system than your makefile (unfortunately).  To be portable you either need to develop (or at least test) on a Debian-derived system, or else have great POSIX discipline.